# Date issues using Angular and Spring Boot

Tags: spring, angular, date, spring-boot, momentjs

I'm using Angular as UI and SpringBoot as REST API. When a date is collected in the User Interface, the format of date is like it:

"2018-05-15T19:00:00.000Z"

After recorded in a Spring Boot API, the date that I've just recorded is retrieved like it:

"dataHora": "2018-05-15T19:00:00.000+0000"

The problem is, when this kind of format is retrieved, the attribute is "undefined". What I need to do to fix it? For I while I didn't paste my code because it could be a question more general.

I've created a class in Angular:

```
export class Rac {
    idRac: number;
    dataHora: Date;
    historico: string;
}
```

The attribute is "dataHora". I try to load the Object when I retrieve from REST API:

```
  carregaRac() {
    this.racService.buscarPorCodigo(this.idRac)
      .then(rac => {
        this.rac = rac;
        this.formulario.patchValue({
          dataHora: this.rac.dataHora,
          historico: this.rac.historico,
        })
         })
      .catch(erro => this.errorHandler.handle(erro));
  }
```

In these example above, when I try to see the "dataHora" value, the console shows to me "undefined"

Comment: What is "attribute"? That looks a normal parseable Date to me through Java.

Comment: You may need `moment.js` to parse this format. Preferrable to stick to standard ISO8601 formats or strict UTC epoch though.

Comment: I've added some code for better understanding. How could I use the moment.js in this case?

Comment: Did you try `dataHora: new Date (this.rac.dataHora)`